# Adding PHP inside Wordpress shortcode

Tags: wordpress, typed

I'm having trouble getting my code to work.

What I would like to do is create a typewriter effect on and single post titles for my wordpress blog.

The shortcode for the typewriter effect is is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[typed string0="First sentence" typeSpeed="40" startDelay="0" backSpeed="40" backDelay="500"]' ) ?>
```

And the post title PHP is

```
<?php echo avada_render_post_title( $post->ID, false, '', '2' ); ?>
```

I've been through all the previous posts and am still having trouble. This is where the code is at now:

```
<?php $the_title = echo avada_render_post_title( $post->ID, false, '', '2' );
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[typed string0="' . $the_title . '" typeSpeed="40" startDelay="0" backSpeed="40" backDelay="500"]' ) ?>
```

It's still not working. Help?!

Edit - It's returning a blank screen.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? That doesn't help us at all. What is the specific issue - an error? The code fails with a blank screen? It doesn't display the title? It doesn't show the effect? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

There is syntax error in your code,try this

```
<?php $title = avada_render_post_title( $post->ID, false, '', '2' );
     echo do_shortcode( '[typed string0="'.$title.'" typeSpeed="40" startDelay="0" backSpeed="40" backDelay="500"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunatly, it's still not working.. it's returning  code on the page now: "Last" data-3="things" data-4="Last:" data-5="Contemporary" data-6="Design" data-7="Manifesto" data-8="breakdown\"" data-type-speed="40" data-start-delay="0" data-backspeed="40" data-back-delay="500">|"